# Prove the Eberlein-Smulian Theorem in the setting of Hilbert spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to prove Exercise 4,  section 13*, chapter V of the book "A Course in Functional Analysis" by "John B. Conway", which states

Prove the Eberlein-Smulian Theorem in the setting of Hilbert spaces. The Eberlein-Smulian Theorem goes as follows:

> If $X$ is a Banach space and $A \subset X$, then the following statements are equivalent.
>
> a) Each sequence of elements of $A$ has a subsequence that is weakly convergent.
>
> b) Each sequence of elements of $A$ has a weak cluster point.
>
> c) The weak closure of $A$ is weakly compact.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is $c\implies a) \iff b)$ clear to you?

Comment: a=>b=>c is not clear for me.

Comment: If there are some implications that *are* clear to you, it would improve your Question to include those in the body of your Question.